# Use dplyr to rename all variables in a df and remove first observation

Tags: r, dataframe, pipe, dplyr, rename

I have imported a dataframe from a csv file. The dataframe looks quite ugly. I would like to rename all variables with the values of the the first observation and to remove this first observation. A colleague of mine gave me an idea with this code.

```
colnames(df) <- lapply(df[1, ], as.character)
df <- df[-1,]
```

The code above works perfectly but I love dplyr:-) Is there any way to do the same using pipes and dplyr?

PS: Sorry in advance if I say something stupid. I am a beginner in R and this is my very first question in Stack Overflow.

Comment: What your colleague suggested is likely an easier approach than using dplyr-pipes for this task. But, why don't you just read the file correctly? (i.e. using `skip = 1`)

Comment: Very nice idea! I just applied it and it worked... but only partly. Now I do not have to remove the first observation but I still have to rename all variables with the names of the skipped observation. Any idea?

Comment: What do you use to read this file? `read.csv`? `read.table`? If you use `read.table`, you just have to add `header=TRUE`.

Comment: You should show us the first lines of your file, and then we'll probably be able to tell you how to read it properly.

Comment: I used read.csv to read the file (a csv file). Adding header=TRUE does not help. The problem is that the original data file has two rows as header.

Comment: Then I don't get it... As docendo discimus said, `skip=1` should do exactly what you want. You should provide an example.

Comment: As I pointed above the suggestion of @docendodiscimus worked but only for the first step (removing the first row) but then I needed to rename all variables with the values of the removed row. The matter is that the quality of the csv file is quite bad because the head of the table has two rows, which causes this issue. Anyway I think will keep the code of my colleague (see my initial post) since it works and I did not find any better alternative. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

```
set.seed(1984)

require(dplyr)

## simulating a data frame

df <- data.frame(a = 1:10,
                b = sample(LETTERS,10, replace = T),
                c = sample(letters,10, replace = T), 
                stringsAsFactors = F)




  head(df)


     a b c
   # 1 1 P y
   # 2 2 A j
   # 3 3 P o
   # 4 4 W u
   # 5 5 U a
   # 6 6 E k

df %>% 
  filter(row.names(.) == 1)  %>%
  as.character(.) -> names(df)

df



   #     1 P y
   # 1   1 P y
   # 2   2 A j
   # 3   3 P o
   # 4   4 W u
   # 5   5 U a
   # 6   6 E k
   # 7   7 W o
   # 8   8 P h
   # 9   9 N b
   # 10 10 O f
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I do the same but without adding row numbers in a column of my data frame?

Comment: the posted code doesn't do that, those are row.names not a column. if you are satisfied with the answer, please consider clicking on the check-mark.

Comment: Sorry! You are right. Good point using row.names(). But this code actually did not work as I expected. It does not remove the first row and the new variables names do not match with the first row values.